# Other way to prohibit a certain C++ class construction except than declaring the constructor private?

Tags: c++, construction

Say I have a class with some **const reference**  member variable and I would like to forbid a certain type of construction. So I would declare the according constructor **private**. Of course, a constructor must initialise all **const reference**  member variables of the class. Doing so, however, results in odd looking code:

```
class A {
};

class B {
  B(const A& a): host(a) {}
private:
  B():host(A()) {}   // This is ugly and not needed !!
  const A& host;
};
```

Is there another way to prohibit a certain construction type except than declaring the constructor private? I do not want to let the compiler write a constructor for me.

Comment: @Jon: Oh man, great! I got into the __bad habbit__ of putting the implementation directly into the class definition. Declaring but not defining the constructor does the trick! Many Thanks!

Comment: @Mat Hmm.. What did you edit in my question (and why)?

Comment: click on the [edited x minutes ago](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7317530/revisions) link to see your question's edit history. I just expanded `ctor` into a full word to match the rest of your text. You can click on the "rollback" link in there if you want `ctor` back.

Comment: Ok, this question was answered (to more than I would have asked for) Many thanks to all! Jon & Nawaz were the first. Jon deleted his answer. So, I guess he doesn't mind the point and this point goes to Nawaz. However, many thanks for the c++11 solutions from Martinhno

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simply don't define this:

```
B():host(A()) {}   // This is ugly and not needed !!
```

That is, the following should do what you want to do:

```
class B {
  B(const A& a): host(a) {}
private:
  //B():host(A()) {}   // This is ugly and not needed !!
  const A& host;
};
```

The idea is if you've defined a constructor that takes parameter(s), then the default constructor is not generated by the compiler. That means, instances of the above class *cannot* be *default* created!

```
 B b1; //error - needs default constructor which doesn't exist!
 B b2(a); //ok - only way to create an instance!
```

---

## C++11 solution

In C++11, you can explicity tell the compiler not to generate a particular constructor as:

```
struct B
{
     B(const A &a) {}

     B() = delete;      //disable
};
```

Not only that. There is more to it, as explained below:

### Now the interesting part

You can also selectively disable constructor(s) for *selected* types which makes `delete` more interesting. Consider this,

```
struct A
{
       A (int) {}
};
```

Object of this class can be created not only with `int` argument, but any type which implicitly converts to `int`.  For example,

```
A a1(10);  //ok
A a2('x'); //ok - char can convert to int implicitly

B b; 
A a3(b); //ok - assume b provides user-defined conversion to int
```

Now suppose, for whatever reason, I don't want the users of class `A` to create objects with `char` or `class B` , which fortunately or unfortunately can *implicitly* convert to `int`, then you can disable them as:

```
struct A
{
     A(int) {}
     A(char) = delete;      //disable
     A(const B&) = delete;  //disable
};
```

Now here you go:

```
A a1(10);  //ok
A a2('x'); //error

B b; 
A a3(b); //error - assume (even if) b provides user-defined conversion to int
```

Online Demo  : http://ideone.com/EQl5R

The error messages are very clear:

> prog.cpp:9:5: error: deleted function 'A::A(char)'
> prog.cpp:10:5: error: deleted function 'A::A(const B&)'

Comment: You could add that to disallow a constructor, one just need to declare it private (no need to define it). This could be useful to disallow the copy constructor, for example.

Comment: @Nawaz That's pretty clever! One must remember this rule when reading code. You think its good habit to rely on this rule and, say, omit the declaration at all instead of just declaring it without defining it?

Comment: There even more to it. The deleted `char` overload is a candidate for other types, like `unsigned`, so now only construction with `int` succeeds. http://ideone.com/r9DD8 (the error message is bizarre, though: where's the ambiguity if only one candidate exists :) )

Answer (score 11):

Just leave it out. As soon as you provide a custom constructor, no other constructor is auto-generated (except for a copy constructor).

If you want to forbid *any* construction – ending up with a class that has only static members – you can simply *declare* the constructor as private, and not *define* it. Such a class is very rarely useful in C++ (since you cannot create instances of it); the only purpose that I can think of is to implement trait classes:

```
template <typename T>
struct type_to_color {
    static char const* value() { return "blue"; }

private:
    type_to_color();
};

template <>
struct type_to_color<int> {
    // Integers are red!
    static char const* value() { return "red"; }

private:
    type_to_color();
}

char const* char_color = type_to_color<char>::value();
char const* int_color  = type_to_color<int>::value();
```

However, this is extremely uncommon: trait classes are abundant in C++ but they never declare their constructors as `private`, it’s just assumed that everybody knows not to instantiate them.

Comment: You could add that to disallow a constructor, one just need to declare it private (no need to define it). This could be useful to disallow the copy constructor, for example.

Comment: @Luc This use-case doesn’t really exist in C++. I’ve added an artificial example (trait class) but you’d never delete their constructor in normal usage.

Comment: I never mentioned disallowing all constructors, just some of them. In the code provided in the question, the copy constructor is still generated. If the OP wants to disallow it, he must declare it private but he does not need to define it (otherwise, he would have the same issue he described, namely having to initialize the member `A`.

Answer (score 2):

I'll post the C++11 solution: *delete* the constructor.

```
class B {
  B() = delete;
  B(const A& a): host(a) {}
private:
  const A& host;
};
```

Comment: Interesting. But isn't the default constructor deleted anyway when declaring another constructor with parameters ?

Comment: @ereOn: Yes, that's true. Making it explicit may help making it clear that you didn't forget that and really don't want one, but it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

As Konrad Rudolph sayd: as soon you provide a custom constructor, no other constructor is auto-generated (except for a copy constructor).

Therefore, other options are:

Declare the constructor private (so that you can't inherit from your class), but do not provide a definition:

```
class B {
public:
  B(const A& a): host(a) {}
private:
  B(); // not implemented!
  const A& host;
};
```

Or in C++11, as R. Martinho Fernandes says:

```
class B {
public:
  B() = delete;
  B(const A& a): host(a) {}
private:
  const A& host;
};
```